# Example that shows the limitations of integrated shrinking

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, property-based-testing, haskell-hedgehog

I just watched [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIv_9T0xKEo) that presents the notion of *integrated shrinking* for property based tests. The approach seems to have some advantages over *type directed shrinking*, however it was pointed out in [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/646k3d/ann_hedgehog_property_testing/) that the integrated shrinking approach does not fit well in the case of monadic generators:

> Doing shrinking in your way does not fit well with a monadic style for generators. Here is an example, consider generating an arbitrary list (ignore termination for now):
>
> ```
> do x <- arbitrary
>    xs <- arbitrary
>    return (x:xs)
> ```
>
> Now, the default behavior of your shrinking would first shrink x (holding xs constant), and then shrink xs (holding x constant), which severely limits the shrinking (the concept of local minimum is now a lot less strong).

I read the above comment as "integrated shrinking might fail to provide a global minimum counter example". However, since [`hedgehog`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog-0.6/docs/Hedgehog.html) seems to be able to find minimal counter examples for failed properties on lists, I was wondering if there is an example that could show the drawback pointed out in the quote above.

Comment: How does `hedgehog` search the space of lists? I would expect it not to take the naive monadic approach (for precisely the reason you point out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In calculus terms, the problem is that you aren't following the negative gradient (steepest descent), instead you're minimizing along 1 axis first and then minimizing along the other axis. Based on this analogy, it is easy to come up with at least a contrived example - consider the function

```
-- f x y = ((x^2 - 1)^2 - 0.2*x) * ((y^2 - 1/2)^2 - 0.1*y)
f x y = (x^4 - 2.2*x^2 + 1) * (y^4 - 1.1*y^2 + 1/4)
```

[See plot on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x+%5E+4+-+2.2+x+%5E+2+%2B+1)+*+(y+%5E+4+-+1.1+y+%5E+2+%2B+1%2F4)).

and we're testing it for the property `f x y > 0`, and let's say a minimal example would have a point closest to the origin `(0, 0)`. Depending on where you first start shrinking, it is entirely possible that you end up close to `(±1, 0)` because you adjust `x` first and then don't allow `y` to change much. However, in an ideal situation, you'd want to end up somewhere close to `(0, ±1/2)` to satisfy the minimality criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference here is an example that involves lists:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Hedgehog
import qualified Hedgehog.Gen as Gen
import qualified Hedgehog.Range as Range

notLargeOrBothNotEmpty :: Property
notLargeOrBothNotEmpty = property $ do
  xs <- forAll randomIntLists
  ys <- forAll randomIntLists
  assert $ length xs < 4 && (xs /= [] && ys /=[])
  where
    randomIntLists = Gen.frequency
      [ (1, Gen.list (Range.constant 0 1) randomInt)
      , (10, Gen.list (Range.constant 1 100) randomInt)
      ]
    randomInt = Gen.integral (Range.constat 1 10)

main :: IO Bool
main = checkParallel $ 
  Group "Test.Example" [("Produce a minimal counter-example", notLargeOrBothNotEmpty)]
```

So hedgehog sometimes will return as a counterexample the lists `( [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ], [])`. However `([], [])` is a smaller counterexample (which sometimes is also reported by `hedgehog`).
￼

In this case, the condition that violates the property is:

```hs
4 <= length xs || (xs == [] && ys == [])
```

If initially a counterexample is found, where `ys /= []` and `4 <= length xs`, the integrated shrinking approach will try to shrink `xs` first, and then will proceed shrinking `ys` keeping `xs` constant, as described in the post I cited in my original question.