# Why the does this shrink tree looks the way it does when using filter

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, property-based-testing, haskell-hedgehog

I'm trying to understand what is the effect that filter has in the shrink tree of a generator when using `hedgehog` *integrated shrinking*.

Consider the following function:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Hedgehog
import qualified Hedgehog.Gen as Gen

aFilteredchar:: Gen Char
aFilteredchar =
  Gen.filter (`elem` ("x" :: String)) (Gen.element "yx")
```

When a print the shrink tree:

```
>>>  Gen.printTree aFilteredchar
```

I'd get shrink trees that look as follow:

```
'x'
 └╼'x'
    └╼'x'
       └╼'x'
               ...

                   └╼<discard>
```

this is, a very deep tree containing only `x`'s, and a `discard` at the end.

Why does the shrink function keeps on returning `x`'s, instead of an empty list, which signals that there are no further shrinks possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gen` is essentially a composition of a probability monad and a tree monad, and the behavior you observe mostly arises from the tree monad and the definition of [`Gen.filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog-0.6/docs/src/Hedgehog.Internal.Gen.html#filter).

Basically, `Gen.filter p g` is a simple monadic loop, `try 0` where:

```
-- simplified body of filter
try k =
  if k > 100 then
    discard  -- empty tree
  else do
    x <- g
    if p x then
      pure x  -- singleton tree
    else
      try (k + 1)  -- keep looping
```

So to understand the tree you got, you must understand the tree monad under the `do` notation here.

## The tree monad

The [`Tree` type in hedgehog](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog-0.6/docs/Hedgehog-Internal-Tree.html#t:Tree) that is internally used by `Gen` looks roughly like this (if you are looking at the linked implementation in hedgehog, set `m ~ Maybe`):

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a [Tree a]  -- node label and children
```

There are many other `Tree`-like types that are monads, and the monadic bind `(>>=)` generally takes the form of a tree substitution.

Say you have a tree `t = Node x [t1, t2, ...] :: Tree a`, and a continuation/substitution `k :: a -> Tree b`, which replaces every node/variable `x :: a` with the tree `k x :: Tree b`. We can describe `t >>= k` in two steps, `fmap` then `join`, as follows. First the `fmap` applies the substitution on every node label. So we obtain a tree where every node is labeled by another tree. For concreteness, say `k x = Node y [u1, u2, ...]`:

```
fmap k t
=
Node
  (k x)                        -- node label
  [fmap k t1, fmap k t2, ...]  -- node children
=
Node
  (Node y [u1, u2, ...])       -- node label
  [fmap k t1, fmap k t2, ...]  -- node children
```

Then the `join` step flattens the nested tree structure, concatenating the children from inside the label with those outside:

```
t >>= k
=
join (fmap k t)
=
Node
  y
  ([join (fmap k t1), join (fmap k t2), ...] ++ [u1, u2, ...])
```

To complete the `Monad` instance, note that we have `pure x = Node x []`.

## The try loop

Now that we have some intuition for the tree monad we can turn to your particular generator. We want to evaluate `try k` above, where `p = (== 'x')` and `g = elements "yx"`. I'm waving my hands here, but you should imagine that `g` evaluates randomly to either the tree `Node 'y' []` (generate `'y'` with no shrinkings), aka. `pure 'y'`, or `Node 'x' [Node 'y' []]` (generate `'x'` and shrink to `'y'`; indeed, "`elements` shrinks to the left"), and that every occurence of `g` is independent from others, so we get a different result when we retry.

Let's examine each case separately. What happens if `g = pure 'y'`? Assume `k <= 100` so we're in the `else` branch of the toplevel `if`, already simplified away below:

```
-- simplified body of filter
try k = do
    c <- pure 'y'     -- g = pure 'y'
    if c == 'x' then  -- p c = (c == 'x')
      pure c
    else
      try (k + 1)

-- since   (do c <- pure 'y' ; s c) = s 'y'  (monad law)   and   ('y' == 'x') = False

try k = try (k + 1)
```

So all the times where `g` evaluates to `pure 'y'` end up simplified away as the recursive term `try (k + 1)`, and we are left with the cases where `g` evaluates to the other tree `Node 'x' [Node 'y' []]`:

```
try k = do
  c <- Node 'x' [Node 'y' []]  -- g
  if c == 'x' then
    pure c
  else
    try (k + 1)
```

As illustrated in the previous section, the monadic bind is equivalent to the following, and we finish with some equational reasoning.

```
try k = join (Node (s 'x') [Node (s 'y') []])
  where
    s c = if c == 'x' then pure c else try (k + 1)

try k = join (Node (pure 'x') [Node (try (k + 1)) []])
try k = join (Node (pure 'x') [pure (try (k + 1))]  -- simplifying join
try k = Node 'x' [join (pure (try (k + 1)))]        -- join . pure = id
try k = Node 'x' [try (k + 1)]
```

In summary, starting from `try 0`, with half probability `try k = try (k + 1)`, and with the other half `try k = Node 'x' [try (k + 1)]`, finally we stop at `try 100`. This explains the tree you observe.

```
try 0 = Node 'x' [Node 'x' [ ... ]]  -- about 50 nodes
```

---

(I believe this also provides at least a partial answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411983/example-that-shows-the-limitations-of-integrated-shrinking), since this shows how shrinking a `Gen.filter` often amounts to rerunning the generator from scratch.)

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to write such a detailed (and helpful answer)!  This seems to clarify why if I would change `Gen.element "yx"` to `Gen.element "xy"` I will most of the times get a singleton tree (however I'm still puzzled as to why I don't *always* get a singleton tree, but that's probably a different question).

Answer (score 1):

While [Li-yao Xia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6863749/li-yao-xia)'s detailed answer correctly describes *how* this happens, it doesn't address the *why*; *why* does it re-run the generator after each shrink? The answer is that it shouldn't; this is a bug. See bug report [Improve Filter](https://github.com/hedgehogqa/haskell-hedgehog/issues/281) on GitHub.

Comment: A fix has been merged https://github.com/hedgehogqa/haskell-hedgehog/pull/282, it will be in the next Hackage release